# What is the meaning of "we lay down in grass" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "we lay down in grass" in the sentence, "Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we lay down in grass" ?

This sentence is in the examples in the Korean-naver dictionary. In the example sentence of this dictionary, this dictionary translates:

> "Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we lay down in grass"

as

> "Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we plant grass"

But Google translator translates "Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we lay down in grass" as "Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we lie on grass".

What does it mean?

Comment: That one is anybody's guess, it didn't translate well.  Maybe it's a translation of idiom.  Plant grass is the only suggested option that would make sense if it is a normal, modern, conversational sentence.

Comment: Seems like it was not proofed by a native speaker. My guess would be "Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we **could** lie on (the) grass", in the sense that if there was no lawn you wouldn't lie on the dirt. Since this is contemplating a possibility, using a would/could pattern is appropriate. The examples you gave don't follow this pattern.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a lawn (a large, flat area of grass), there are two ways of doing it. You can [sow](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sow) grass seeds, or you can buy rolls of grass that is growing in a thin layer of soil (called turf) and then [lay](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lay) it in the same way as you would lay a carpet. This is what turf looks like:

[image]

> Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we lay down in grass

This sentence is not correct. It could be made understandable by removing the **in**, but still not natural or grammatically correct. More natural sentences would be:

> Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we made a lawn.
>   Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we sowed some grass seeds.
>   Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we laid some turf.

You could also use the words lay, grow or plant in relation to a lawn. The term **lay down** is not used about turf or lawns. This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lay%20down%20a%20lawn%2C%20lay%20a%20lawn%2C%20make%20a%20lawn&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clay%20down%20a%20lawn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clay%20a%20lawn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20lawn%3B%2Cc0) shows that **make a lawn** is considerably more common than **lay a lawn**, and **lay down a lawn** hardly appears at all.

Note that, when we use **would** in a conditional sentence (one with an **if**), we normally backshift the tense of the verb in the if clause, so make->made, sow->sowed, lay->laid.

This is what the first sentence would be like if we made it unconditional:

> Our front yard will be a lot nicer when we make a lawn.

Comment: "To make a lawn" sounds odd and non-idiomatic to my ear.

Comment: @mattdm: it's not my favourite term, but if you google it you will find that it is quite widely used. Here is an example: http://www.crocus.co.uk/features/_/articleid.982/.

Comment: Maybe it's a British thing? I did that search, and the _vast_ majority of occurrences are "make a lawn great" or "make a  lawn mower".

Comment: @mattdm: Vast majority? About 50% of the ones that I looked at. British? "If you're undecided about whether to make a new lawn or repair an old one, let the lawn itself answer your dilemma." J.I.Rodale, an American who knew a thing or two about gardening. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._I._Rodale

Comment: Isn't the translation meant to be "Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we lay down grass"? (Just remove "in")

Comment: @Bohemian: this is an example sentence from a Korean dictionary. It's wrong. As I explained in my answer, if you simply remove **in** you get something that's more understandable but is still grammatically incorrect and unnatural.

Answer (score 4):

There is a possible mistranslation you are looking at

> Our front yard would be a lot nicer if we lay down grass.

would have the meaning that planting grass (*laying down grass*) would make the front yard nicer.  *Lay down* is slang-ish for *putting down* or *planting*.

Also

> lay down *in* grass

implies the grass is long and overgrown.